# How delete extension in a perl script

Tags: perl, rename

A silly question, but it make me crazy!
I have a script to remove "fat" data in a bvh file. (Biovision mocap file..).
Works fine, but it create a double extension... (The name.bvh.bvh)
I just only need one extension (*.bvh, not the *.bvh.bvh!!!)
Here is the code:

```
@files = <*.bvh>;
foreach $file (@files) {
        open  (OLD, $file) || die "Couldn´t open $file: $!\n";
        open  (NEW, ">$file.bvh") || die "Couldn´t open $file.bvh: $!\n";
            while (<OLD>) {
                $line = $_;
                if (/Normal/) { while (<OLD>) { last if /}/; } $line => ""; }
                if (/normalIndex/) { while(<OLD>) { last if /[]]/; } $line = ""; }
                $line  =~  s/[-+]?[0-9]\.[0-9]+e[+-][0-9]+/0/g;
                $line  =~  s/([-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})[0-9]+/$1/g;
                $line =~ s/0\.00/0/g;
                $line =~ s/[ ]+/ /g;
                $line =~ s/[\t]+/ /g;
                $line =~ s/^ //g;
                print NEW $line;

            }
            close OLD;
            unlink ($file);
            close NEW;          
            }
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Why do not store result of processing in temporary file and once conversion complete rename it to original filename?

Answer (score 4):

```
@files = <*.bvh>;
```

This gives you a list of the files that have a `.bvh` extension. So it will end up containing something like:

```
('foo.bvh', 'bar.bvh', 'baz.bvh')
```

Then you walk the array with this code:

```
foreach $file (@files) {
  ...
}
```

Each time round this loop, `$file` will contain a value from your array. One the first iteration, for example, `$file` will contain `foo.bvh`.

Then you open input and output files:

```
open  (OLD, $file) || die "Couldn´t open $file: $!\n";
open  (NEW, ">$file.bvh") || die "Couldn´t open $file.bvh: $!\n";
```

As `$file` contains `foo.bvh`, your new file (which is created using the name `"$file.bvh"`) will be called `foo.bvh.bvh`.

The naive fix would be to remove the `.bvh` from the `open()` statement:

```
# DON'T DO THIS
open  (OLD, $file) || die "Couldn´t open $file: $!\n";
open  (NEW, ">$file") || die "Couldn´t open $file.bvh: $!\n";
```

This won't work as your old and new files will now have the same name and when you open your new file for writing, it will truncate the file and remove all of your input data.

You'll need to rename a file at some point. And the easiest approach is to keep your existing filenames and once you have processed each file, rename it to the original name.

```
# And then at the end of your loop
# Note that as you're copying the new file over the old one,
# there's no need to delete the old one.
close OLD;
close NEW;
rename("$file.bvh", $file);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just insert `rename("$file.new", $file);`

as shown in your code:

```
@files = <*.bvh>;
foreach $file (@files) {
        open  (OLD, $file) || die "Couldn´t open $file: $!\n";
        open  (NEW, ">$file.new") || die "Couldn´t open $file.new: $!\n";
            while (<OLD>) {
                $line = $_;
                if (/Normal/) { while (<OLD>) { last if /}/; } $line => ""; }
                if (/normalIndex/) { while(<OLD>) { last if /[]]/; } $line = ""; }
                $line  =~  s/[-+]?[0-9]\.[0-9]+e[+-][0-9]+/0/g;
                $line  =~  s/([-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})[0-9]+/$1/g;
                $line =~ s/0\.00/0/g;
                $line =~ s/[ ]+/ /g;
                $line =~ s/[\t]+/ /g;
                $line =~ s/^ //g;
                print NEW $line;

            }
            close OLD;
            unlink ($file);

            close NEW;          
            rename("$file.new", $file);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this is not the way however you can get the output.

Use this Module for renaming function

```
use File::Copy;

@files = qw(first.bhv second.bhv third.bhv);
foreach $file (@files) {
```

Just remove the `extension` on the original file

```
    (my $rem_ext = $file)=~s/\.bhv$//;
```

rename the file without `extension`

```
    rename($file, $rem_ext);
```

Just read the without `extension` file

```
    open  (OLD, $rem_ext) || die "Couldn´t open $rem_ext: $!\n";

    open  (NEW, ">$file") || die "Couldn´t open $file.bvh: $!\n";
        while (<OLD>) {
             ...
        }
        close OLD;
```

Delete the files without `extension` which is created by ourself.

```
        unlink($rem_ext);
        close NEW;          
        }
```

It will works

Comment: `rename` doesn't need the File::Copy module, and you should consider using three-argument `open`s with lexical file handles. But, you don't need to read the file to write it out again. You've already renamed the file so you don't need to do the extra work.

Comment: Great and understood.